# What is the correct way of polling a list of libusb_pollfd structures?

Tags: c, polling, libusb

The structure of pollfd is:

```
struct pollfd {
        int fd;             /* file descriptor */
        short events;       /* requested events */
        short revents;      /* returned events */
}
```

The structure of libusb_pollfd is:

```
struct libusb_pollfd {
         int fd;         /* Numeric file descriptor. */
         short events;
}
```

The structure of the poll function is:

```
int poll(struct pollfd *fds, nfds_t nfds, int timeout);
```

What is the correct way of polling a list of libusb_pollfd structures? Do you use the poll function with some kind of modification? Or is there a libusb function which is supposed to be used?

Comment: See `libusb_get_pollfds`

Comment: @stark That function only retrieves the list of file descriptors. I want to know how to poll that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only way to achieve this, is using the following code:

```
    struct libusb_pollfd **pollfds; 
    struct pollfd pollfd_array[n];

    pollfds = libusb_get_pollfds(context);
    for (i=0; pollfds[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        pollfd_array[i].fd = pollfds[i]->fd;
        pollfd_array[i].events = pollfds[i]->events;
    }

    poll_ret = poll(pollfd_array, i, 0);
```

Which is what I was trying to avoid. Let me know if there's a better way.